# can you pass self to lambda in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-plugins, paperclip

I want to define a class method that has access to a local variable. So this would be different for each instance of the class.  I know you can make a class method dynamic with lambda like when you use it with named_scope.  But can this be done for values that are specific to an instance?

In detail it is the has_attached_file method for the paperclip plugin in rails.  I want to pass a lambda for the styles hash so that the image styles can be based off of attributes of the object stored in the DB.  Is this possible?

Comment: Can you clarify - is this lamdba being invoked by the has_attached_file code, and therefor out of your hands?  Because you can pass parameters to lamdbas when you call them, and can pass "self" just as easily as anything else.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** First, the question (*Can you pass self to lambda?*) and the problem you're trying to solve (dynamic styles with paperclip) don't fully match up.  I won't answer the original question because it's not entirely related to your problem, and rampion took a valiant stab at it.

**I'll instead answer your paperclip question.**

> *In detail it is the `has_attached_file` method for the paperclip plugin in rails. I want to pass a lambda for the styles hash so that the image styles can be based off of attributes of the object stored in the DB. Is this possible?*

**Yes, it is possible.**  In paperclip, the `:styles` option can take a Proc.  When the attachment is initialized, if a Proc was used, the attachment itself is passed to the Proc.  The attachment has a reference to the associated ActiveRecord object, so you can use that to determine your dynamic styles.

For example, your `has_attached_file` declaration might look something like this (assuming a User and avatar scenario where the user can customize the size of their avatar):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => lambda { |attachment| 
    user = attachment.instance
    dimensions = "#{user.avatar_width}x#{user.avatar_height}#"
    { :custom => dimensions }
  }
end
```

Comment: @bwizzy - you should click the check mark by Ryan's answer then, to note that (1) he answered your question and (2) to reward him for doing so.

Comment: Thanks, sorry this is my first post.  Thanks for all the quick replies and great detail.

Comment: I'm facing this very same problem, and solved it using the approach that @ryan-mcgeary suggested. But I also need to use delayed_job, so instance variables won’t work. How could I address this?

Answer (score 9):

Ok, you're being unclear.

Local variables in ruby begin with a lowercase letter (like `foo`, `bar`, or `steve`), and are lexically scoped (like `C` variables).  They have nothing to do with "an instance of a class"

Instance variables in ruby begin with an `@` sigil (like `@foo`, `@bar`, or `@carl`), and are in scope whenever the current value of `self` is the object they are stored in.

If you want a method that can access the instance variables of an object directly, that's called an instance method.  For example, `battle_cry` and `initialize` are both instance methods:

```
class Character
  def initialize(name)
    @name=name
  end
  def battle_cry
    @name.upcase + "!!!"
  end
  def Character.default
    new("Leeroy Jenkins")
  end
end
```

A class method, by contrast, is a method for a `Class` object, and doesn't have access to any of the instance variables of that object.  In the above example,
`default` is a class method.

If you want a (class or instance) method that triggers a change in or gets a value from the current scope, ruby uses a type of callback called a block.

```
class Character
   ATTACKS = [ "Ho!", "Haha!", "Guard!", "Turn!", "Parry!", "Dodge!", "Spin!", "Ha", "THRUST!" ]
   def attack
     ATTACKS.inject(0) { |dmg, word| dmg + yield(word) }
   end
end

person = Character.default
puts person.battle_cry

num_attacks = 0;
damage = person.attack do |saying|
  puts saying
  num_attacks += 1
  rand(3)
end
puts "#{damage} points of damage done in #{num_attacks} attacks"
```

In the above example, `attack` uses the `yield` keyword to call the block passed
to it.  When we call `attack`, then, the local variable `num_attacks` is still
in scope in the block we pass it (delimited here by `do ... end`), so we can
increment it.  `attack` is able to pass values into the block, here
they are captured into the `saying` variable.  The block also passes values
back to the method, which show up as the return value of `yield`.

The word `lambda` in ruby usually means the `lambda` keyword, which is used
to make blocks into freestanding, function like objects (which themselves are usually
referred to as `lambda`s, `proc`s, or `Proc`s).

```
bounce = lambda { |thing| puts "I'm bouncing a #{thing}" }
bounce["ball"]
bounce["frog"]
```

So I think what you're asking is whether you can pass a `Proc` in place of a `Hash` 
for an argument to a method.  And the answer is "it depends".  If the method only
ever uses the `#[]` method, then yes:

```
class Character
  attr_accessor :stats
  def set_stats(stats)
    @stats = stats
  end
end

frank = Character.new("Victor Frankenstein")
frank.set_stats({ :str => 7, :dex => 14, :con => 9, :int => 19, :wis => 7, :cha => 11 })

monster = Character.new("Frankenstein's Monster")
monster.set_stats(lambda do |stat_name|
  rand(20)
end)
```

However, it might use some other `Hash` specific methods, or call the same key multiple times,
which can produce weird results:

```
monster = Character.new("Frankenstein's Monster")
monster.set_stats(lambda do |stat_name|
  rand(20)
end)

monster.stats[:dex] #=> 19
monster.stats[:dex] #=> 1
```

In which case, you may be better off caching the requests in an intermediate hash.  This is fairly easy,
since a `Hash` can have an initializer block.  So if we change the above to:

```
monster.set_stats(Hash.new do |stats_hash, stat_name|
  stats_hash[stat_name] = rand(20)
end)

monster.stats[:dex] #=> 3
monster.stats[:dex] #=> 3
```

The results are cached in the hash

To see more about `Hash` block initializers, see `ri Hash::new`:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------- Hash::new
     Hash.new                          => hash
     Hash.new(obj)                     => aHash
     Hash.new {|hash, key| block }     => aHash
------------------------------------------------------------------------
     Returns a new, empty hash. If this hash is subsequently accessed
     by a key that doesn't correspond to a hash entry, the value
     returned depends on the style of new used to create the hash. In
     the first form, the access returns nil. If obj is specified, this
     single object will be used for all default values. If a block is
     specified, it will be called with the hash object and the key, and
     should return the default value. It is the block's responsibility
     to store the value in the hash if required.

        h = Hash.new("Go Fish")
        h["a"] = 100
        h["b"] = 200
        h["a"]           #=> 100
        h["c"]           #=> "Go Fish"
        # The following alters the single default object
        h["c"].upcase!   #=> "GO FISH"
        h["d"]           #=> "GO FISH"
        h.keys           #=> ["a", "b"]

        # While this creates a new default object each time
        h = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = "Go Fish: #{key}" }
        h["c"]           #=> "Go Fish: c"
        h["c"].upcase!   #=> "GO FISH: C"
        h["d"]           #=> "Go Fish: d"
        h.keys           #=> ["c", "d"]
```