# Rails: Being frustrated with NoMethodError (undefined method...) error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a model Team and Division described as a division should have many teams:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :division

  has_attached_file :logo, :styles => { :large => "120x180>", :thumb => "100x100>", :tiny => "25x25>" },  
      :url => "/assets/images/:style/teams/#{self.division.name}/:basename.:extension",  
      :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/images/teams/#{self.division.name}/:basename.:extension"
end


class Division < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :teams
end
```

I want to get the name of division of the team by using: `#{self.division.name}` to include in the string but it doesn't work at all.

Error given:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `division' for #<Class:0x007f80179b68f8>):
```

Even when I use `#{self.name}` to get the name of the team, but it return only the class name: `"Team"`. In console, I call them just fine:

```
1.9.3p194 :009 > team = Team.find(4)
  Team Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `teams`.* FROM `teams` WHERE `teams`.`id` = 4 LIMIT 1
 => #<Team id: 4, name: "Arsenal F.C.", league_id: nil, division_id: 1, stadium_id: 2, history: "This is Arsenal F.C. history file", wins: 1, losses: 1, win_percentage: 1.0, created_at: "2012-08-25 09:25:22", updated_at: "2012-08-27 01:54:08", logo_file_size: 29303, logo_updated_at: "2012-08-27 01:54:08", logo_content_type: "image/png", logo_file_name: "arsenal.png"> 
1.9.3p194 :010 > team.name
 => "Arsenal F.C." 
1.9.3p194 :011 > team.division.name
  Division Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `divisions`.* FROM `divisions` WHERE `divisions`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
 => "English Premier Division" 
1.9.3p194 :012 >
```

I am trying to call `self.name` (name of the team) or `self.division.name` (name of the division of the team) in team.rb, not in a controller.

Any idea why? Because of the self hasn't loaded yet? How to solve this?

**Update:** I really like shioyama's solution because we can pass Proc to paperclip. However, my rails_admin and paperclip and this solution seem still throwing error about gsub on the form. I found another thread [Dynamic use of :default_url in Paperclip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784224/dynamic-use-of-default-url-in-paperclip) that will cover my problem. shioyama's solution works fine without rails_admin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `self` inside a class definition, it refers to the class itself, not to an instance of that class. To get at the instance you have to use a `lambda`:

```
has_attached_file :logo,
  :styles => { :large => "120x180>", :thumb => "100x100>", :tiny => "25x25>" },  
  :url => lamda { |attachment|
    team = attachment.instance
    "/assets/images/:style/teams/#{team.division.name}/:basename.:extension"
  },  
  :path => lambda { |attachment|
    team = attachment.instance
    ":rails_root/public/assets/images/teams/#{team.division.name}/:basename.:extension"
  }
```

`attachment.instance` gets the instance that the attachment is attached to (in this case an instance of the `Team` class). See the [paperclip documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb#L38).

See also this answer: [can you pass self to lambda in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109496/can-you-pass-self-to-lambda-in-rails)